# removing element from multiple data frames which are in a list

Tags: r

I have multiple data frames which are read into r from spreadsheets. All data frames have the same columns but some observations within columns are entered incorrectly (during data entry) and r treats some as posixct and others as integers and factors etc. The problem is that the rbindlist function has problems with that on some machines (it may depend on the version of data.table). The good news is this problematic variable is not analysed and could be removed. How do I filter the multiple data frames within the list to do this neatly?

I have tried different code but none seems to work across all data frames within the list. Here is some dummy data:

```
lst <- list(a = 1:4, b = 4:8, c = 8:10)
lst1 <- list(a = 1:4, b = 4:8, c = 8:10)

iist2<-list(lst, lst1)

if("b" %in% names(iist2)) iist2 <- iist2[ - which(names(iist2) == "b")]
```

But it does not work however if it is just lst or lst1 then the above works. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
lapply(iist2, function(i)i[!names(i) %in% 'b'])
```

Comment: perfect thank you both. Each example worked well but I am going to run with lapply as didn't need to load another package @akrun. On another note is there any way to apply as character or as factor to a list element that is found within multiple data frames within a list. For example, could I change element 'a' (to character) in lst and lst1 within iist2? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

We can use `discard` or `keep`

```
library(purrr)
map(iist2, ~ keep(.x, names(.x) != "b"))
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$a
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[1]]$c
#[1]  8  9 10


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$a
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]$c
#[1]  8  9 10
```